# Creating navigation in the controller or in the view

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter

Hello I have a question about something. I am busy creating a website with CI and I have conquered a problem/question to myself. Where do you put the code for the navigation in CI? in the controllers or in 1 view that you always include?

Comment: I take it these weren't the answers you were looking for?

Comment: The answers don't look correct to me.. somehow I tought the navigation should go into a controller and not into a view..

Comment: If you already decided prior to asking the question that you wanted your navigation in the controller, then you shouldn't have asked the question. You weren't really looking for which method is best practice, you were just looking for someone to agree with you

Comment: No, I want to know a way how to achieve this. but the answers that are given are not correct in my opinion.. ( could be that I am wrong, tough a explanation for that would be nice )

Comment: See my update. That's the last update I'm making since this seems like more of an opinion question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually my navigation is on the top of my websites so I just create a header.php with all the html,header,meta tags. then after the body tag I have the code necessary for the navigation.

You can pass some variables or just use the uri segment to find what is the current page, so you can have your navigation highlighted, just like the navigation on the stackoverflow, right now the Questions section highlighted.

You can create a template view, on your controller do something like this:

```
public function index(){
    $data['title'] = 'Site title'
    $data['current_page'] = 'Home'
    //the view you want to load
    $data['view'] = 'home';
    //loads the vars across all views
    $this->load->vars($data);
    //loads the view wich will have our template
    $this->load->view('template');
}
```

Now our view template will be something like this, remember you can change the layout if you want, if you a have like a left column or something like that

```
<?php 
$this->load->view('header');
//this is the view we loaded on our controller
$this->load->view($view);
$this->load->view('footer');
?>
```

For example my view header has my navigation system and I use the variable current_page to highlight the menu anchor for home, and the title variable to have a dynamic title across the pages

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

This is the last response I'm posting here.

Since you are dead set on having the navigation in your controller, here is what you can do. Load the data as an array in your controller. Have each link that is going to be in the navigation be a part of that array. Pass the data to your view (ideally your template.php view that I talked about earlier), and run the array through a foreach loop.

Since you don't want to have a completely separate view file for your navigation because you don't like only having 5 lines of code, then put it in your template file. So your template should look like this:

```
<head>
    <?php $this->load->view('elements/head'); ?>
</head>
<header>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($menus as $menu): ?>
            <li><a href='<?php print $menu["url"] ?>'><?php print $menu["title"] ?></a></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</header>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <?php $this->load->view($content); ?>
    </div>
</body>
<footer>
    <?php $this->load->view('elements/footer'); ?>
</footer>
```

All of this being said, it is against MVC pattern to actually echo this data in the controller. You can declare your data in the controller, but **you should load it in a view.**

Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11751624/codeigniter-dynamic-navigation), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876961/efficient-website-navigation-with-codeigniter), and even more so [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905024/code-igniter-this-navigation-logic-in-a-controller-or-view) all agree that a separate navigation view is best.

---

I typically have a default "template.php" view that is included on every page. The content inside is loaded dynamically.

In this case, I would suggest putting your navigation in a "header.php" view file (assuming that your navigation is at the top), and load that into a "template.php" view. This will separate blocks of code and make it easy for you to change just your navigation later on. Your template file should look something like this:

```
<head>
    <?php $this->load->view('elements/head'); ?>
</head>
<header>
    <?php $this->load->view('elements/header'); ?>
</header>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <?php $this->load->view($content); ?>
    </div>
</body>
<footer>
    <?php $this->load->view('elements/footer'); ?>
</footer>
```

Comment: Hm ye I tought something like that.. but is it not wrong to have more code then a simple echo or foreach loop in a view?

Comment: If you have 2 lines of code in header.php, by all means put it in this file. This is just a way to modularize your views. Regardless, it should be in a view. You can pass the data from your controller if you want/need to, but you need to put it in a view for it to be seen.